# What's wrong with this implementation of random access iterator in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, implementation

I have tried implementing my own random access iterator for the class called MyIntArray. I have written all the functions that were necessary for the concept of random access iterator.
I wonder what's wrong with this implementation of Random Access Iterator in C++? as when changed from

```
using iterator_category = random_access_iterator_tag;
```

To this one

```
using iterator_category = bidirectional_iterator_tag;
```

The sorting works fine. I have tried other iterator types which worked correctly. But when it comes to Random access one the sorting doesn't work and still can't figure out why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;

class MyIntArray{
    private:
        int * arr;
        const int size;
    public:
        class MIAIterator{
            private:
                int index;
                int * start;
            public:
                using iterator_category = random_access_iterator_tag;      
                using value_type = int;
                using difference_type = int;
                using pointer = int*;
                using reference = int&;
                MIAIterator(int* s,int i=0):index(i){start=s;};
                MIAIterator(const MIAIterator& it):index(it.index),start(it.start){};
                MIAIterator& operator=(const MIAIterator& it);
                bool operator==(const MIAIterator & it){return this->index==it.index;}
                bool operator!=(const MIAIterator & it){return this->index!=it.index;}
                bool operator <(const MIAIterator & it){return this->index<it.index;}
                bool operator <=(const MIAIterator & it){return this->index<=it.index;}
                bool operator >(const MIAIterator & it){return this->index>it.index;}
                bool operator >=(const MIAIterator & it){return this->index>=it.index;}
                MIAIterator& operator++();
                MIAIterator operator++(int);
                MIAIterator& operator--();
                MIAIterator operator--(int);
                MIAIterator operator+(int n);
                MIAIterator operator-(int n);
                int operator-(const MIAIterator & it_end){return it_end.index-this->index;}
                int& operator[](int i){return *(start+i);}
                int& operator*(){return *(start+index);}
                friend MIAIterator operator+(int n,const MIAIterator& mia);
        };
        friend class MIAIterator;
        MyIntArray(int s,int n);
        MyIntArray(initializer_list<int> il);
        ~MyIntArray();
        void print();
        MIAIterator begin(){return MIAIterator(&arr[0],0);}
        MIAIterator end(){return MIAIterator(&arr[0],size);};
};

int main() {                        
    MyIntArray mia={4,5,8,-1,3,-8,-16,2};
    mia.print();
    std::sort(mia.begin(),mia.end());
    mia.print();
    for(int a:mia){
        std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
    }
}
//Friend Function
MyIntArray::MIAIterator operator+(int n,const MyIntArray::MIAIterator& mia){
    return MyIntArray::MIAIterator(mia.start,mia.index+n);
}

//MyIntArray Class
MyIntArray::MyIntArray(int s=10,int n=0):size(s){
    arr=new int [size+1];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        arr[i]=n;
    }
}
MyIntArray::MyIntArray(initializer_list<int> il):size(il.size()){
    arr=new int [size+1];
    int i=0;
    for(auto it= il.begin();it!=il.end();it++,i++){
        arr[i]=(*it);
    }
}
MyIntArray::~MyIntArray(){
    delete [] arr;
}
void MyIntArray::print(){
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        std::cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}


//The MIAIterator Class
MyIntArray::MIAIterator& MyIntArray::MIAIterator::operator=(const MIAIterator& it){
    if(this==&it)return (*this);
    this->index=it.index;
    this->start=it.start;
    return (*this);
}
MyIntArray::MIAIterator& MyIntArray::MIAIterator::operator++(){
    this->index+=1;
    return (*this);
}
MyIntArray::MIAIterator MyIntArray::MIAIterator::operator++(int){
    this->index+=1;
    return MIAIterator(this->start,this->index-1);
}
MyIntArray::MIAIterator& MyIntArray::MIAIterator::operator--(){
    this->index-=1;
    return (*this);
}
MyIntArray::MIAIterator MyIntArray::MIAIterator::operator--(int){
    this->index-=1;
    return MIAIterator(this->start,this->index+1);
}
MyIntArray::MIAIterator MyIntArray::MIAIterator::operator+(int n){
    return MIAIterator(this->start,this->index+n);
}
MyIntArray::MIAIterator MyIntArray::MIAIterator::operator-(int n){
    return MIAIterator(this->start,this->index-n);
}
```

Comment: For this {4 5 8 -1 3 -8 -16 2}
I get this result {-16 5 8 -1 3 -8 -16 2}
while sorting

Comment: I don't know which parts is unnecessary for you, maybe you could just look at parts which you think are important, I guess it's better to have the whole code than to have some part of it which doesn't have problems and try to find the problem there

Comment: It's pretty simple I guess, sorry, if you can't help me with this code, then thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
int operator-(const MIAIterator & it_end){return this->index - it_end.index;}
```

It should be opposite

```
int operator-(const MIAIterator & it_end){return it_end.index - this->index;}
```

Comment: Oh gush, I knew it was a mistake of not being careful, that was the only small part which I didn't notice, thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

```
int operator-(const MIAIterator & it_end){return this->index - it_end.index;}
```

This is the correct way